# maxw and if depending on whether image ist portrait or landscape

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to set only maxW for given images. But I want to give another value for portrait or landscape format.

What I have tried is this (does'nt work, that's why I am asking..)

```
  10 = IMAGE
  10 {
    stdWrap.wrap = <div class="col_3-4">|</div>
    file {
      import = fileadmin/_processed_/
      import.data = levelmedia:-1
      import.listNum = 0
      treatIdAsReference = 1
      maxW = 585
      maxW.if {
        value.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|0
        isGreaterThan.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|1
      }
      maxW = 385
      maxW.if {
        value.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|1
        isGreaterThan.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|0
      }
    }
  }
```

For the case of equality of width and height I did'nt treat this here..

Who can help please?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost ok, but first block of *maxW* is ignored, because it *always* is rewritten by second block.

So, you should try to use **override** here:

```
  <snip>
  maxW = 585
  maxW.override = 385
  maxW.override.if {
    value.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|1
    isGreaterThan.data = TSFE:lastImageInfo|0
  }
```

At the end you say: use 585. And override value with 385, but override only if height > width.

Comment: Hm, thanks! But for me that doesn't work. The image is always rendered with 585px width.

Comment: By the way, I'm using typo3 6.0.4. Thanks.

Comment: @SvenMertens just tried my snippet on 4.7 installation and it works. The only difference, that I put filename directly in a way `page.110.file = fileadmin/user_upload/02.png`. Maybe, it has something to do with new **FAL**?